# why adding \pagestyle{fancy} gives compile error with tex4ht?

Tags: fancyhdr, tex4ht

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{$\cos \left(x\right)$}
test
\end{document}
```

Gives this error

```
make4ht foo1.tex
........
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (./foo1.aux)
! Argument of \im:g has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.6 \section{$\cos \left(x\right)$}

?
```

commenting out `\pagestyle{fancy}` the error goes away.

Also, which is more interesting, changing `\section{$\cos \left(x\right)$}` to `\section{$\cos x$}` the error goes away!  i.e.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{$\cos x$}
test
\end{document}
```

No error. So it looks like it is the use of `\left` and `\right` is what caused the problem for text4ht when using `fancyhrd`

I will change my code so to avoid loading `fancyhdr` when in tex4ht mode to bypass this.

But the question is, why make4ht fails like this? Should make4ht handle this better?

TL 2019 with latest updates as of 2 days ago.

Comment: I am quite sure it is not a good idea to use `fancyhdr` with `tex4ht`. I may add some code to suppress it's loading, but for the moment it is best to use the conditional loading

Comment: @michal.h21 I agree with you. I found this by accident. I do not need fancyhrd in tex4ht. But I thought the error itself could indicate some other issue somewhere. I already changed by code to avoid loading this package when using tex4ht. But it will be good if tex4ht could detect such problems internally and bypass them.

Comment: I guess it changes the sectioning commands somehow. I will look at this issue tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is definition of the `fancy` page style:

```
\def\ps@fancy{%
  \f@nch@ifundefined{@chapapp}{\let\@chapapp\chaptername}{}% for amsbook
\f@nch@ifundefined{MakeUppercase}{\def\MakeUppercase{\uppercase}}{}%
\f@nch@ifundefined{chapter}%
 {\def\sectionmark##1{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
        \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
      \fi ##1}}{}}%
  \def\subsectionmark##1{\markright {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
    \thesubsection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}}%
 {\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth {\MakeUppercase{\ifnum
      \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}{}}%
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
      \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}%
}
\ps@@fancy
\gdef\ps@fancy{\@fancyplainfalse\ps@@fancy}%
\ifdim\headwidth<0sp
    \global\advance\headwidth123456789sp\global\advance\headwidth\textwidth
\fi}
```

As you can see, it redefines `\sectionmark` and other section related commands. It seems that it clashes with `tex4ht`. As the functionality provided by `fancyhdr` doesn't make sense for the HTML output, I think it is best to just redefine the `\ps@fancy` command to do nothing. The only catch is that because the `\pagestyle` command can be used in the document preamble, the patch cannot be incorporated using the `fancyhdr.4ht` file. We must use the `tex4ht` mechanism for patching packages in `\usepackage`. Here is the full updated `usepackage.4ht:

```
% usepackage.4ht (2019-06-24-13:58), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2019-06-24-13:58}

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package xr,xr-hyper,eso-pic,expl3,savetrees,biblatex,fancyhdr,xeCJK,polyglossia,fontspec,tikz,pdfbase,graphics,xcolor,imakeidx,minted,,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\def\:temp{xr}\ifx \@currname\:temp
   \AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
   \def\XR@[#1]#2{%
    \Configure{AtBeginDocument}{\XR:[#1]{#2}}{}}%
}

\fi
\def\:temp{xr-hyper}\ifx \@currname\:temp
   \def\eat:optional[#1]{}
\AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
   \def\XR@[#1]#2{%
     \Configure{AtBeginDocument}{\XR:[#1]{#2}}{}\@ifnextchar[\eat:optional{}}%
}

\fi
\def\:temp{eso-pic}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AddToShipoutPicture{\@ifstar{}{}}
\let\AddToShipoutPictureBG\AddToShipoutPicture
\let\AddToShipoutPictureFG\AddToShipoutPicture
\fi
\def\:temp{expl3}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion%
\xenunidelblock{Latin-expl3}%
\AtEndOfPackage{\xeuniuseblock{Latin-expl3}}
\fi
\fi
\def\:temp{savetrees}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{savetrees}
\fi
\def\:temp{biblatex}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\blx@mknoautolang{%
    \blx@lbxinput{\blx@languagename}%
    {}{}%
  }%
  \def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}

}
\fi
\def\:temp{xeCJK}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{xeCJK}
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\setCJKmainfont{o m o}{}
\let\setCJKsansfont\setCJKmainfont
\let\setCJKmonofont\setCJKmainfont

\DeclareDocumentCommand\setCJKfamilyfont {m o m }{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\newCJKfontfamily {o m o m}{\expandafter\gdef\csname #2\endcsname{\relax}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\xeCJKsetup{m}{}
% }
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xeuniuseblock{CJK}
}
\fi
\AtEndOfPackage{
  \let\orig@xpg@define@keys\xpg@define@keys
  \def\xpg@define@keys#1{%
    \orig@xpg@define@keys{#1}%
    \define@choicekey+[xpg@setup]{#1}{direction}[\val\nr]{LR,RL}[LR]%
    {
      \togglefalse{#1@RL}%
      \ifcase\nr\relax%
        \csgappto{init@extras@#1}{%
          a:PolyglossiaRtl%
        }
      \or
        \csgappto{init@extras@#1}{%
          \b:PolyglossiaRtl%
        }
      \fi
    }%
    {\xpg@warning{#1: Invalid value \val\space for key "direction"}}%
}}

\def\:temp{fontspec}\ifx \@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\fontspec
    \:dontusepackage{fontspec}
  \else
    \input usepackage-fontspec.4ht
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{tikz}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\use:tikzlibrary\usetikzlibrary
\def\find:externalize#1external#2\@nil{%
\if\relax#2\relax\else
  \let\tikz:externalize\tikzexternalize
  \renewcommand\tikzexternalize[1][]{\tikz:externalize[##1,mode=only graphics]}
    \tikzset{%
      tex4ht inc/.style={%
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
          \includegraphics[]{####1.pdf}%
        }%
      }
    }
    \tikzset{tex4ht inc}
  \fi
}
\renewcommand\usetikzlibrary[1]{%
  \use:tikzlibrary{#1}%
  \find:externalize#1external\@nil%
}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{pdfbase}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \let\old:outputpage\@outputpage
  \def\@outputpage{\old:outputpage{}}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{graphics}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvips}{graphics}
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{xcolor}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvips}{xcolor}
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{imakeidx}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \PassOptionsToPackage{noautomatic}{imakeidx}
\fi
\def\:temp{minted}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
    \define@booleankey{minted@opt@g}{breaklines}{}{}{}%
  }
\fi

\def\:temp{fancyhdr}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
    \def\ps@fancy{}
  }
\fi



\endinput
```

The part that handles with `fancyhdr` is small:

```
\def\:temp{fancyhdr}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
    \def\ps@fancy{}
  }
\fi
```

This is the result:

[image]